# malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc Assertion failed in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I am keep getting this error `vidprocess: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.`

I am freeing memory just once at this step:

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *ep;     
dp = opendir (folder_input);
if (dp != NULL) {
    while ( (ep = readdir (dp)) && MAXVIDS != 0 ) {
        char *filename;
        filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(ep->d_name));
        strcpy(filename, ep->d_name);
        int len = strlen(filename);
        char *last_three = &filename[len-3];
        char trailer_file_name[100];
        int in_if = 0;
        if (strcasecmp(last_three, "MOV")  == 0) {
            strcpy(trailer_file_name, ep->d_name);
            MAXVIDS--;
            in_if = 1;
        }
        else if (strcasecmp(last_three, "MP4")  == 0) {
            strcpy(trailer_file_name, ep->d_name);
            MAXVIDS--;
            in_if = 1;
        }
        free(filename);
```

This is the only place where I use `free()`. If I don't use this part I don't get the error above, so I am just assuming that I get an error due to memory freeing, but I did not understand why that is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory for `filename`:

```
    filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(ep->d_name));
```

This does not allocate space for the terminating null byte, you need `strlen(ep->d_name) + 1` bytes. Also, as a side note, `sizeof(char) == 1` *always*.

Also, for this sort of error a good memory debugger will save you a LOT of time. I suggest something like valgrind if it's available for your platform/arch, or another similar tool.

By overrunning the allocated buffer, you may corrupt internal data structures used by `malloc()` to do its bookkeeping, which is why you see a crash in `free()`.